# BigQuery(standard SQL) grouping values based on first CASE WHEN statement

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my query with the output below the syntax.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN id = 'RUS0261431' THEN value END AS sr_type, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN id in ('RUS0290788') AND value in ('1','2','3','4') THEN respondentid END) AS sub_ces,
COUNT(CASE WHEN id IN ('RUS0290788') AND value in ('5','6','7') THEN respondentid END) AS pos_ces,
COUNT(*) as total_ces
FROM `some_table`
WHERE id in ( 'RUS0261431') AND id <> '' AND value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

As you can see with the attached table I'm unable to group the values based on Id RUS0290788 with the distinct values that map to RUS0261431. Is there anyway to pivot with altering my case when statements so I can group sub_ces and pos_ces by sr_type. Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLISg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your WHERE condition to WHERE id = ('RUS0261431'). Only records with this value will be selected so you do not have to repeat this in the CASE statements.